# Python 3.4 Selenium handle chromedriver exception

Tags: python, selenium, error-handling, python-3.4, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium for python with chromedriver. Unfortunately I havn't found a way to handle errors raised by chromedriver in python!

If I use selenium to open any Webseite:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opts = Options()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}  
opts.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
driver.delete_all_cookies()

driver.get("https://www.google.de/")

#Some more actions

driver.close()
```

And while the script is running if I close the browser window (manually), I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

If I put the python code above entirely in a try/except bracket, if chrome brakes, the exception is not executed! Instead the entire programm brakes!

Is there a way to handle the error raised by chromedriver in python?

Thanks for your advise!

EDIT:
I guess my question wasn't expressed very well. My script is working fine, I just want to handle the exception if someone closes the browser window manually. For now my entire python tool including my gui crashes...

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in selenium right now when you use `driver.close()` as the last step of your script. You should be using `driver.quit()`. `driver.close()` is to just close the current window (tab) and leave the browser open. `driver.quit()` tells selenium to quit the chromedriver service as well

Comment: Thanks! This is not answering my question, but its very helpfull information!

Comment: You can't catch it because the exception is happening while python is trying to complete the script.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with me:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
```